# .txt com senha em C?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Estou mexendo com manipulação de arquivos .txt e eu queria saber como fazer para criar um arquivo .txt com uma senha em C, para que esse arquivo não possa ser aberto pelo bloco de notas ou outro programa sem a senha. E que depois se eu quisesse abrir o arquivo eu pudesse utilizá-lo no programa em C usando a senha.

Codificar o conteúdo do .txt eu já sei fazer, tipo mudar o conteúdo dele para símbolos e depois recuperar, mas o que eu quero fazer é tornar o arquivo não "abrível" sem a senha.

Comment: Tem uma pergunta similar no [Soen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090282/protecting-a-file-by-a-password). A sugestão foi de comprimir para (`.zip` por exemplo) e depois bloquear com uma senha, pode ser que ajude ;)

Comment: Acho que todas as soluções passam por criptografia. Pode ser um arquivo criptografado, um zip criptografado contendo o arquivo, uma pasta ou uma unidade criptografada, etc.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de eu criar um .TXT Apenas para leitura diretamente do Devc++? Talvez isso me ajude com o que eu queri fazer

Comment: @DivinSphere: Não vejo outra maneira de se fazer isso de forma confiável e efetiva sem o uso de algum algoritmo criptográfico. A propósito, qual é o seu intento em fazer tal coisa ? Já conhece o [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy) ?

Comment: Eu desenvolvi um questionário em C que pode ler Perguntas pelo bloco de notas, ou seja qualquer lessoa pode criar perguntas e colocar no programa para responder, Tipo um Show do milhão com perguntas nl bloco de notas, Eu fiz aqui um sistema para codificar o bloco de notas e acho que vou ter que me contentar assim mesmo, a gente cria perguntas no bloco de notas usa o programa para codificar e depois é só arrastar que o programa decodifica e começa o jogo

Comment: É um jogo de perguntas e respostas que qualqurr pessoa poderia criar suas perguntas e enviar para outras pessoas para responder, Com essa codificação que eu fiz por enquanto está até tranquilo de usar, mas agora meu professor da faculdade me perguntou se eu conseguiria fazer para armazenar a pontuação e a matrícula da pessoa online, Agora outro desafio pra mim kkk não faço ideia de como utilizar online no C xD

Comment: Vou me contentar com a codificação do conteúdo mesmo e tentar ver algo com Online no C para tentar fazer sistema de pontuação mas valeu por tudo o/ não sei nem se C tem algo sobre online kk

Answer (score 1):

Sei que já passou tempo mas a pergunta tem uma resposta clara: **um arquivo texto nada mais é do que um sequencial de caracteres**. Assim sendo, **não apresenta qualquer característica que permita fazer nada além de armazenar tais sequenciais de caracteres** que podem ser lidos perfeitamente por quaisquer programas.

A exceção, *pra não dizer que não tem*, fica com a *permissão* de leitura/execução/escrita de arquivos *de acordo com usuários de um dispositivo ou aplicação*, onde cada usuário manda e desmanda em seus próprios arquivos. Por exemplo: fulano@gmail.com não lê e-mails de beltrano@gmail.com a menos que este permita. *Mas essa gerência de arquivos é outro tema completamente diferente e que não se aplica ao caso*.

Para você atingir seu objetivo, pode seguir uma das sugestões que te deram na pergunta: desde criar um ZIP (ou equivalente) com o arquivo texto puro. Claro que não seria tão trivial quanto simplesmente manipular um simples arquivo de texto.

Outra alternativa é criar seu próprio modelo de arquivo com sua criptografia. Assim, só seu programa conseguiria descriptografar